# Does the C++ Arrow Operator (->) return an lvalue in all cases?

Tags: c++, c++11

According to the C++ Primer book, "The arrow operator requires a pointer operand and yields an **lvalue**". Is that always the case? For example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using std::string; using std::vector;

int main()
{
     vector<string> temp {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};
     vector<string>::iterator iter_str = temp.begin();
     bool result = iter_str->empty();  //the result of iter_str->empty() is not an lvalue right?

     return 0;
}
```

- When we take the expression iter_str->empty() for instance it can't be the left hand operand of an assignment operator right?
- And if the arrow operator returns an lvalue does it not have to, at all times? Or are there exceptions to this rule?

Comment: The result of the arrow operator here is just the member function `std::string::empty` and is an lvalue. Though that value can't be used at all except to immediately call it; the result of the function call operator is the rvalue of type `bool`.

Comment: @aschepler, that means the return value of iter_str->empty() is not actually the boolean value, instead the empty() method in the string right? And that value is immediately executed being a method and it's value was the output I received. Okay thanks, but how is the empty() method itself an lvalue since it can't be on the right side of an assignment operator, that what's confusing me.

Comment: @aschepler Good answer - should be posted as one!

Answer (score 5):

What the book is saying is that `iter_str->` yields an lvalue, that is the value category of the object you are using is an lvalue.  The entire expression of `iter_str->empty()` is still an rvalue since `empty` returns by value.  Take for example a class like

```
struct integer {
    int x;
    int& ref() & {
        return x;
    }
};
```

Here, `ref` can only legally be called on an lvalue object because of the *ref-qualifier*.  If we have a function like

```
integer* get_integer_ptr() { return new integer; }
```

then we can legally do

```
int foo = get_integer_ptr()->ref();
```

even though the pointer is an rvalue, it is accessing an lvalue object so the call to `ref` is legal.

---

Yes, there is a memory leak but we can ignore that for the purpose of the example.

Comment: this works fine, primary because ref() returns a reference to an lvalue object(x) which is modifiable, but what if it return a function like above, which cannot be on the left hand operand of an assignment operator? Or (x) was defined as a const?

Comment: @octopus If `ref` just returned an `int` it would still be fine, see [this live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/070287c03c71dbae).  Remember when you do `ptr->function()` what the compiler does is change it to `(*ptr).function()`.  That `*ptr` yields an lvalue and that is why the arrow operator is said to yield an lvalue.